# ZF2: How to propagate Controller return to layout template?

Tags: viewmodel, zend-framework2, zend-framework-mvc

I'm returning data from Controller like this:

```php
/**
 * Password request sent
 *
 * @return array
 */
public function passwordRequestSentAction ()
{
    return array(
        'foo' => $this->bar,
    );
}
```

But `$this->foo` is null within layout.phtml even though its correct within controller/passwordRequestSent.phtml

I had to create postDispatch method in my abstract controller and link to it in attachDefaultListeners() and do this in postDispatch:

```php
$e->getViewModel()->setVariables($e->getResult()->getVariables());
```

Is that really the way to go? I simply want to share all my variables across, no matter if its layout or page template.

Comment: Out of curiosity - why would you want to do this?

Comment: @Fge I have solved most of my needs for this with placeholders. But still I sometimes can see the need. For instance, every single .phtml in my project gets passed a $messages array and sends it to a helper, like $this->showMessages($messages). I have quite some boilerplate code throughout my view scripts, and in order to reduce it I would have to start using partials (a viable solution, but I still will need to call it every view script) or make the layout have the boilerplate code.

Comment: yep, I've some logic in the layout header which I want to share across all pages. I wanted to have all code and logic which is really on all pages to be in layout. Not to include some menu headers in every phtml file I've.

Answer (score 2):

You can access the layout-template by calling `$this->layout()`:

```php
class MyController extends AbstractActionController
{
    public function myAction()
    {
        $layout = $this->layout();
        // Returns the ViewModel of the Layout
    }
}
```

For more information & samples check [the manual's examples](http://packages.zendframework.com/docs/latest/manual/en/zend.view.html#zend.view.quick-start.usage.layouts).

However in most cases I'd suggest writing a viewhelper for these tasks - especially for navigation/... This encapsulates the controller's logic from viewing tasks like `I want the navigation displayed here` or `Show me the user's login box`. Same goes for almost every type of status messages.

Comment: Missed this part of documentation, will look thru. Thanks. As a first impression I will probably need to rethink how to do headers/footers.

Comment: @MarekNos Any outcome of your rethinking?